# How to use react component in setting popup for leaflet

Tags: reactjs, leaflet

I am trying to put popup in map. For setting content, use of `<div>` is not a problem, but when I try to insert a React component, it shows a blank popup.

```
layer.on({
            'mouseover': (e) => {
                L.popup({
                    closeButton: false,
                }).setLatLng([e.latlng.lat, e.latlng.lng]).setContent(`<div>{<TooltipFeatureDetails />}</div>`).openOn(this.map);
            }
        });
```

Comment: If you haven't already, you should take a look at [react-leaflet](https://react-leaflet.js.org/). You can write your Map code almost entirely in JSX using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML does not understand JSX. Thus, `<TooltipFeatureDetails />` would not be rendered correctly.

You can try converting JSX to HTML using `ReactDOMServer.renderToString()`

Try:

```
.setContent(`<div>${ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<TooltipFeatureDetails />)}</div>`)
```

Read here: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html#rendertostring

Comment: Absolutely brilliant. Thanks :)